# Jquery changPage function won't stop caching requests

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Ok, so I'll do my best to explain how this is supposed to work.  This is for a mobile so I'm using Jquery mobile.

1)  User selects from a list of items -> taken to external not yet in DOM page.

2)  User POSTS a form to another external page not yet in DOM.

3) This page refreshes a div every 2 second using this code getting the status of the element we just submitted (takes around 15 seconds to get to our final status point ususally).

```
<script>
$('#status').empty();    
setInterval(function() {
$('#status').load('/call/status/<?php echo $call->sid?>');
}, 2000);
</script>
```

4) Once the the final status message is reached we want to refresh and take them to an element that is in the first set of elements (in point 1).  I'm using this code as the final message to trigger the change page event back to the first set of pages.

```
<script>$.mobile.changePage("#inbox",{transition:"slideup"} ); </script>
```

The weird thing is that I can get this working but only the first time.  Once I go back through this process it has the original #status div still cached and tries to take me back to #input prematurely.

As you can see I have a $('#status').empty(); running so should this div already be destroyed when it comes around the next time?

Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't the $("#status").empty() be inside of the interval? I don't know how your scripts are setup, so maybe not.

Comment: If I do that the #status div flashes obnoxiously.  I don't think it should make a difference.  But I'm not really an expert obviously.

Comment: Yeah, which is why doing this isn't a good way of doing it. Many server calls.

Comment: What's the better way of doing it?

Comment: Well, I don't know exactly what your application is for, or what exactly this particular piece of code does, but whenever you have to have send a loop of requests to the server like this it always weighs heavily on your application. It can cause your application to crash and such. If your application isn't being used by many users, then this will be "okay", however the BEST way is to use technology like Socket IO which keeps a continuous connection to the server, for real-time data. Also, you do not want to use SetInterval for this. I will post an answer with a "better" solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my recommended code, this will not empty the container though. This will not fix your initial problem, however I think you'll find it works smoother. This will ensure that you are not sending the request to the server before the previous request(s) have finished, which setInterval does, it doesn't know if the request has been completed or not. I recommended (when you're going to involve any server calls, or even anytime really. SetInterval isn't any good) to at least use this method, rather than interval.

```
function status(){

    $('#status').load('/call/status/<?php echo $call->sid?>', function(){
    //this is to be performed on success of the load
    setTimeout(status, 2000);
    }); 

}
setTimeout(status, 2000);
```

I would be happy to try to troubleshoot your initial problem though, but I would need more details to understand exactly how it works.